# Spring boot library and application structure

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, microservices

I am implementing a Microservice library, which can be used by other developers to create microservices without taking the pain of implementing internal features like health, metrics, Kafka communication etc.

I am planning to create a multi-module maven project and I will install the library jar separately and this jar will be added as dependency in the application pom.xml.

This is the folder structure I am using:

**Library**

```
MicroServiceLibrary  
     |  
     |____mvnw  
     |    
     |____pom.xml  
     |  
     |____src/
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.oracle.ofsc</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice-library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </project>
```

**Application**

```
MicroServiceApplication  
     |  
     |____mvnw  
     |    
     |____pom.xml  
     |  
     |____application/  
               |  
               |___pom.xml  
               |  
               |___src/
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-multi-module</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>application</module>
</modules>
```

**application/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.oracle.ofsc</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice-application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!--dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ofsc</groupId>
        <artifactId>microservice-library</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here are my questions:
1. Am I implementing the right directory structure?
2. What is the purpose of pom.xml inside MicroServiceApplication?
3. Where should I specify spring-boot-starter-parent artifact - In library or application pom.xml?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Am I implementing the right directory structure?

This is totally up to your project module structure. But, you need one pom.xml at project root folder.

> 2. What is the purpose of pom.xml inside MicroServiceApplication?

You need pom.xml to download required jar from maven central repository.

> 3. Where should I specify spring-boot-starter-parent artifact - In library or application pom.xml?

As far as I understood, they are microservice and they might be running independent. right ? Then, you should include  `spring-boot-starter-parent` in both.